# How to create a hover effect for static background images...?

Tags: javascript, hover

I'm not a JS-guy but I am trying to find a way to make a "bubble" appear with content in it when a visitor mouses over a background image. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="certifications">
        <p class="gold left">Microsoft Gold Partner</p>
        <p class="sdvo center">Service Disabled Veteran Owned Small Business</p>
        <p class="ibm right">IBM Authorized Partner</p>
</div><!-- end #certifications -->
```

And, the CSS looks that controls that area looks like this:

```
#certifications {
height: 111px;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 40px;
}

#certifications p {
margin-top: 20px;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#certifications .gold {
background-image: url(images/microsoft-gold.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline;
height: 70px;
width: 33%;
float: left;
margin-top: 25px;
padding: 0;
}

#certifications .sdvo {
background-image: url(images/sdvosb.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline;
height: 100px;
width: 30%;
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
}

#certifications .ibm {
background-image: url(images/partners/IBM.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline;
height: 99px;
width: 31%;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: -50px;
}
```

When someone mouses over any of the three background images, I'd like the effect to appear (ideally using just CSS, but if I need to use JS then it's not a big deal). The key thing is making it backwards compatible to IE6.

I'm going to keep researching this and will post if I find the answer, but I'd truly appreciate any insight you guys might have to offer. Thanks for your time and insight!

Comment: You could use CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class, except with IE6 that only works on `<a>` elements so you'd need to use JavaScript. Are you opposed to using a library like jQuery (which has its own [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function)?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery .hover() method. For more see [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: The jQuery .hover() method you mentioned looks pretty easy to implement, but how would I target a class as opposed to an element?

Comment: Okay, I tried the .hover() and .tooltip() from jQuery and it doesn't seem to be working. [Here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) is what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm just running in circles. :(

Comment: _"how would I target a class as opposed to an element?"_ - jQuery has the concept of a selector, similar to CSS selectors, where you specify how to select elements and then the operation you want to perform on whatever elements matched. As with CSS you can select by ID: "#someid" or class: ".someClass" or html tag "div", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I a fan of lazy coding and not reinventing the wheel. These guys have already done it a dozen different ways.
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/